# docker without sudo on WSL2

Tags: iptables, docker, windows-11, wsl2, ubuntu-20.04

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ running `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install` will let you run Docker without sudo, however, when I try to do it, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Missing system requirements. Run the following commands to
[ERROR] install the requirements and run this tool again.
[ERROR] Alternatively iptables checks can be disabled with --skip-iptables .

########## BEGIN ##########
sudo sh -eux <<EOF
# Load ip_tables module
modprobe ip_tables
EOF
########## END ##########
```

When I run that command I get this error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594470/54354 the only real way to make it so ip_tables is available is by...  compiling the kernel from scratch? Is there a less extreme solution to making it so that Docker can be ran without root?

Comment: What's your use-case for running as non-sudo/non-root?  I'll see if I can reproduce and come up with suggestions, but it would be good to know the *why* so that I don't offer up anything that won't work for your use-case.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I'm using Docker to run multiple versions of PHP and I have stuff like `php80` or `php74` aliased to `docker run -it` commands in my .bashrc. If dockerd isn't running it needs to be started with sudo but I don't do it a lot so I'm always having to look it up when I need to do it and it's a bit of a PITA so I'd like to start dockerd up in .bashrc as well if possible.

Comment: Hmm, according to your tags, you are on Windows 11, right?  If so, you can run the Docker daemon at startup via `/etc/wsl.conf` -- See [my Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814529/11810933) on the topic.  It also includes a way to do it in `~/.bashrc` for Windows 10 users.  Would that suffice?  Technically, in that case, you are still running it as root, but there's not much of a difference in behavior (or security, for that matter).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - looks promising! I'll try it out when I get home! Thanks!